# (React Hooks): one setstate is not working, but double setstate is working?

Tags: reactjs, async-await, react-hooks, use-effect, react-state

this is my code:

```
function Users() {

    const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {

        const getUsersData = async () => {
            setLoading(true);

            const response = await fetch('https://api.github.com/users');
            const data = await response.json();

            setUsers([...data]);

            setLoading(false);
        }

        getUsersData();

    }, [users])

    return (
        <div className="container my-4">
            <div className="row">
                {loading ? (
                    <p>loading...</p>
                ) : (
                    users.map((user) => <UserItem key={user.id} user={user}/>)
                )}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

after setUsers, setLoading(false) is notworking.

in the chrome developer tools, loading state is still "true" not "false".

if i using double setLoading(false) its work, loading state is "false" now.
like this:

```
useEffect(() => {

        const getUsersData = async () => {
            setLoading(true);

            const response = await fetch('https://api.github.com/users');
            const data = await response.json();

            setUsers([...data]);

            setLoading(false);
            setLoading(false);
        }

        getUsersData();

    }, [users])
```

why 1 setLoading not working but 2 setLoading is working ?

Comment: what happens if you use try catch block? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch

Comment: @JuniusL. Okkey, i will try that.

Comment: @JuniusL. there is no error.

Comment: in the useEffect, im trying to not passing second argument. Its working, but why ?

useEffect(() => {

}, [])

Comment: it causes a loop, everytime ```users``` changes useEffect gets called, you shouldn't put it as a dependency.

Comment: aaah, alright. it seems I have to learn more about the useeffect. Thank you @JuniusL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. in map method you are reading whole object as name instead you should read one property  user={user.login}
2. call setLoading(false) after calling getUsersData()
3. in useEffect users dependency not needed

here is working code

```
function App() {

              const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
              const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

              useEffect(() => {
                const getUsersData = async () => {
                  setLoading(true);

                  const response = await fetch("https://api.github.com/users");
                  const data = await response.json();

                  setUsers([...data]);
                };
                getUsersData();
                setLoading(false);
              }, []);

              return (
                <div className="container my-4">
                  <div className="row">
                    {loading ? (
                      <p>loading...</p>
                    ) : (
                      users.map(user => <UserItem key={user.id} user={user.login} />)
                    )}
                  </div>
                </div>
              );
            }
```